# inner join different tables, based on column value

Tags: sql

Help me please with my select.
I have i table carriers, which contains information about carrier: car_id, car_name, car_zones (this value is table name, which has this carrier's zones data), car_rates_exp (this value is table name, which has this carrier's export rates data), car_rates_imp (this value is table name, which has this carrier's import rates data), car_href (this value is href to tracking api of this carrier)

Also I have table 'orders', among all fields, it has column carrier_id, from_country, weight and shipper_rate. I want to make a select in which I want to make inner join with table, but this table name in query has to be different, based in carrier_id. I tried to make this query, but it does not work:

```
SELECT o.id_order, 
       o.from_country, 
       c.firstname, 
       c.lastname, 
       o.carrier_id, 
       ot.name as order_type, 
       z.Zone_name, 
       cr.car_zones, 
       cr.car_name, 
       cr.car_href, 
       o.invoice_amount,  
       o.rated_weight, 
       o.shipping_rate, 
       o.shipping_rate_my_fee, 
       o.customs_tax, 
       o.customs_tax_2, 
       o.customs_my_fee, 
       o.total_shipping_fee, 
       o.total_my_costs, 
       o.1kg_price, 
       o.my_profit, 
       o.goods_for_ship, 
       o.waybill,  
       o.prev_DHL_fee, 
       o.customer_paid, 
       os.name as order_status, 
       os.color 
FROM orders o 
  inner join customer c on o.id_customer = c.id 
  inner join order_types on on o.order_type = ot.id 
  inner join (select car_zones 
              from   carriers 
              where  car_id=o.carrier_id) z on o.from_country = z.id 
  inner join carriers cr on IF(o.carrier_id = 0, 1, o.carrier_id) = cr.car_id
  inner join order_status os on o.order_status = os.id
where import_or_export = 'import' AND o.active > 0
```

So the string

```
inner join (select car_zones from carriers where car_id=o.carrier_id) z on o.from_country = z.id
```

does not work, can you please help me to solve this situation?

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: Include **id** in the sub-query as `(select id, car_zones from carriers where car_id=o.carrier_id) z on o.from_country = z.id`

Comment: You cannot have a subquery in the `FROM` clause that refers to another table in the `FROM` clause. Do you want this: `inner join carriers z on o.carrier_id = z.car_id and o.from_country = z.id`? If not, what instead?

Comment: horsten Kettner, thanks for you reply.
No i want like 
inner join zones_DHL z on o.from_country = z.id 
or 
inner join zones_UPS z on o.from_country = z.id 
or 
inner join zones_Fedex z on o.from_country = z.id

Comment: As far as I understand you have table names in your table `carriers` and now you are trying to get the table name for the `carrier_id` and join with that table. You cannot do this. In queries you write you must know the table and column names; you cannot tell the DBMS to read one of your tables and interpret its content as a column or table name. Why do you even have different tables `zones_DHL`, `zones_UPS` etc. instead of one table `zones` with a `carrier_id`?

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly. 
I have different tables of zones, cause some carrier has 10 countries, some has 253 countries, and some of them have different names (like USA and United States), and some of them devide 1 country to few zones.
Those data is updated by carrier often, and I just import those info into DB from excell sheet.

Comment: Anyway, only because I'm selling items where some items are available in 2 colors and other in 10, I don't make this two tables. This simply means: your data model is inappropriate. Have a carrier table, a carrier_country table (containing the carrier-specific country names) and a carrier_country_zone table (with only one dummy zone for countries that are not divided in zones).

Comment: Yes, but colors are are all time same, you just link them on your goods by ID. But with carriers is not so simple. Some carriers have different names (e.g. China, and People Republic of China, USA and United States). DHL devide world into 7 zones, but UPS devide it on 9 zones. Some of them service only 10 countries, some of them 253.

Comment: All of them have different prices, depend on zones, also have different fuel surcharge and VAT, wich changes every month.

I understand what you mean, Yes I can do one catalog with zones for each carrier by my hands, and rename all countries to their proper names. But Next column is shipping cost, which also need to join with carrier table. And in ths case I cannot make one catalog, cause of different zones and different prices

Answer (score 2):

The subquery doesn't contain a field id to which you are joining to

```
o.from_country = z.id
```

Add the id to the subquery.

Comment: No, you missunderstand me... 
in this select '(select car_zones from carriers where car_id=o.carrier_id) - I want to get only value car_zones this is table name, which contains all countries with their id. They are all different for each carrier. So I want to get a table name with wich i will do inner join

Comment: it is also like select t.order_name, t.car_id, r.country from table t, inner join case t.car_id 
if 1 then 'dhl'
if 2 then 'ups' end 
as r on t.id = r.car_id

the case function will switch table names, depend on car_id, and then we will get table name, which contains all information about this carrier, and can join it.

but due to those curriers will be about 10 pcs, I want to wtite thise code, without need to modify it, when some new corriers will add in future